# as3 + JavaScript for Facebook graph API

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to connect (login) to Facebook graph via JavaScript and after that to use the as3 API for queries?

Answer (score 0):

The Actionscript API already uses the JavaScript API to communicate with FB, so yes, it is possible (and in fact it is what actually happens when you log in with the AS3 api).

You'll get an access token back when you log in. If you pass that back into your .swf, you can use it to make requests. Otherwise, as long as your browser has been through authentication, you should be able to get the token again like this:

```
var auth:FacebookAuthResponse = Facebook.getAuthResponse();
var token:String = auth.accessToken;
```

And then, for example, post to somebody's feed:

```
var user:String = auth.uid;
var values:Object = 
{ 
    access_token: token,
    name: "Post Title",
    picture: "http://www.mysite.com/myimage.jpg",
    link:"http://www.mysite.com",  
    description: "App description", 
    message: "Message you want to post here."
};

Facebook.api("/" + user + "/feed", callback, values, URLRequestMethod.POST);
```